# What pools will allow asic block erupters these days?

Tags: block, asic

I'm a Ubuntu cgminer/bfgminer guy and purchased 6 asic block erupters and a newbie to mining.  Could never get into slushpool, but have been mining for poolin for about a week and really don't see any results anywhere.

1-poolin.com?  -  I did create for ETH,  a coinbase wallet entry, although the poolin 'sub-account' dialog field never showed the pasted wallet address  and  still see nothing where it  doesn't even show the hash rate.   Possibly I'm not looking in right place and/or this hardware isn't making any kind of contribution even though the terminal screen shows the miners cranking away full speed, now for some days.

2-other pools? -  I have been reading and realize that block erupters are now considered too slow or inadequate for most pools.   Does anybody recommend of know of a pool where  6 block erupters could make an acceptable contribution and they would allow little me to mine and see the results of dedicated mining hours?

Certainly I do plan to enlarge this configuration but would be very grateful to see some results before making more investment.    Again thanks kindly for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You're never going to see anything with these.

Block erupters are simply... ancient. The ones I had did a few hundred megahahes - a reasonable ASIC you'd buy today does 10+ *tera*hashes.

1 terahash = 1,000,000 megahashes

You're essentially never going to contribute enough to a pool to see a reward share that you can actually withdraw.

If you intend to start mining now, you will need to invest several thousand dollars into modern, capable machines to do so.

Comment: Thanks for response.   So none of these pools have any crypto currency that can be mined with 15 or 16 asic block erupters at 330 MHs rate, right?    Nothing will surface as anything earned, right?    Just trying to get started and thinking I maybe shouldnt have purchased these.      Why do they sell them?        Again thanks.   ))- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_mining_pools